# What is the difference between notifications of Firebase and FCM?

Tags: notifications, firebase

I am using Firebase, but I don't know what is different between notifications in Firebase and FCM.

I think notifications of Firebase can only send messages, whereas FCM can send **and get** messages.

Is it right?

Comment: Firebase Notifications are actually FCM itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Notifications is built on Firebase Cloud Messaging and shares the same FCM SDK for client development. For testing or for sending marketing or engagement messages with powerful built-in targeting and analytics, you can use Notifications. For deployments with more complex messaging requirements, FCM is the right choice.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/#how_does_it_work

Answer (score 3):

> Use the **Notifications** console GUI to **compose and send** notifications to all supported message targets. Firebase **Cloud Messaging** handles the **routing and delivery** to targeted devices.

- Firebase **Notifications** offer a console which users can use to send a notification without writing a single line of code. So, it is used to **create and send the notification**
- Firebase **Cloud Messaging** is a cross-platform messaging solution that lets you reliably deliver messages at no cost. So, it is used to **route and deliver the message/notification**

source:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KpTSpVh9SfY